# Python/Django - No module named

Tags: python, django

I try to work with a class from Django views.

**sync.py**

```
import requests

class Sync:

    def do():
        r = requests.post('http://192.168.1.7/api/report_x')
        print(r.response)
```

**views.py**

```
import sync

def index(request):
    s = Sync()
    s.do()
    return HttpResponse("Hello, this is index")
```

When I access index from the browser I get:

> global name 'Sync' is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change the first line to `from sync import sync`

Answer (score 5):

Direct reference to `Sync()` will not work with current import statement.

Change it to either:

```
from sync import Sync
```

Or use:

```
s = sync.Sync()
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're writing Python, you should actually write Python. Python is not Java.

You should not be using a class here at all. Define a standalone function called `sync`, import it with `from sync import sync`, and just call it. No need for an instance of something that has no state.

Comment: tiny edit (but since the author might simply paste): `from sync import Sync` (capitalisation)

Comment: No. I'm suggesting OP doesn't use a class at all. Style for functions is `lower_case_with_underscores`.

Answer (score 1):

Import the name before using it

```
from sync import Sync
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your file directory is proper and not the reason for the error, change your code to the following:

```
from sync import Sync    # simply import sync just calls the synv.py file, not the Sync class

def index(request):
    s = Sync()
    s.do()
    return HttpResponse("Hello, this is index")
```